# conditions on multypling sub-groups (so it would be a new sub-group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Ok, so we know that if G is abelian and A,B are here sub-groups, then AB, defined by: $AB\:=\:\left\{ab\::\:a\in A,\:b\in B\right\}$ is a new sub-group.

Now, I'm given another condition and I need to show that AB is a sub-group:
$$b^{-1}Ab\in A,\:\forall b\in B$$

I know that $b^{-1}Ab$ is also sub-group of A. I know eather that all memebers of that sub-group are commutative with any $b\in B$, because:

$b^{-1}ab = a$ and multypling the inverse of b from the left we will get the abelian condition. But our last suspicion is the there are elements in A, which arent in the sub-group, who are not abelian with b.

So that are my thoughts until now, and I didnt actually used too much in the data that the condition is true for all $b\in B$.

So how do I show it ? Do I need to show that $A\in b^{-1}Ab$ eather to show that all of the group abelian (although I dont see how it is possible from the given data to proof that)?

Comment: That $b^{-1}Ab\subseteq A$ does not imply that $b$ commutes with the elements of $A$.

Comment: Suppose for example that $G$ is a non-abelian group and that $A=G$. Then there is a $b\in G$ which does not commute wih all the elements of $A$, and yet obviously we have $b^{-1}Ab\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no condition $b^{-1}ab=a$, only that $b^{-1}Ab=A$.

Now, take $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$.
Then
$$(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)=a_1(b_1a_2b_1^{-1})(b_1b_2)\in AB.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didnt think about that trick.

Comment: You wellcome...